# Cómo consultar con un texto campos de texto y números a la vez en una consulta de PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

Hasta ahora tengo esa consulta armada, Quisiera saber como consultar ese texto en un campo `integer` sin que muestre error, porque me da error

> nullpointerexception.

```
 public void BuscaMuestraUsuario(String texto,DefaultTableModel a){try {
    a.setRowCount(0);
    Database db = Database.getInstance();

        ResultSet rs = db.consultaBase("select id_usuario, dni_usuario, apellido_usuario, nombre_usuario, telefono_usuario, es_admin"+
    " from usuarios"+" where nombre_usuario like ('"+texto+"') or apellido_usuario like ('"+texto+"') or dni_usuario similar ('"+ Integer.valueOf(texto) +"')");
        Object [] row = new Object[8];

        while (rs.next()){
            row[0]=rs.getInt(1);
            row[1]=rs.getInt(2);
            row[2]=rs.getString(3);
            row[3]=rs.getString(4);
            row[4]=rs.getInt(5);
            row[5]=rs.getBoolean(6);

        }
        a.addRow(row);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se realizo la busqueda de usuario.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Rodrigo!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta para que obtengas buenas respuestas, te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues la pregunta no es muy clara pero básicamente noto varios errores en ese método:

1.No deberías usar Integer para un DNI, estos se deben manejar siempre como cadenas de texto ya que los integer los debes usar si requieres operaciones o alguna funcionalidad derivada del mismo, lo cual no requiere un DNI

2.Creo que no es la forma más optima de llenar un jTable desde la base de datos. Aquí te doy un ejemplo de como resolverlo de una forma más genérica

```html
FillTable(MyTable, "select * Customers;");


public void FillTable(JTable table, String Query)
{
    try
    {
        CreateConnection();
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(Query);

        //To remove previously added rows
        while(table.getRowCount() > 0) 
        {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }
        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while(rs.next())
        {  
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {  
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow()-1,row);
        }

        rs.close();
        stat.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e)
    {
    }
}
```